# Localized hometown from facebook connect

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

When using facebook connect with devise, I get the hometown like this:

```
... hometown=#<Hashie::Mash id="116045151742857" name="Munich, Germany">
locale="de_DE" ...
```

Is there a way to get each users hometown in his own locale or at least in one set locale (de_DE in my case), e.g. "München, Deutschland" with the facebook API?

I don't want to sport my own database of hometowns if I don't have to.

Comment: I am using config.omniauth :facebook, "appid", "appkey", :scope => "email,user_hometown".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note tested, but you could try adding &locale=de_DE to the graph call.  You can get the locale from the user object so potentally could customise this per user. Do a "/me" graph call to get the locale, then do a "/me?locale=de_DE" to get it in the user's language.

As I've said, I've not tested so it may not change the content of the field (e.g. Germany -> Allemande) but worth a shot if you've not tried it.

Comment: Sure works with google, so worth a try. Unfortunately, I don't do the call myself but devise or omniauth-facebook and I don't see an option for locale. Will dig into it though.

Comment: this works, unfortunately it is not configurable. I monkey patched omniauth-facebook method raw_info.